# heatmap layer colours based on value

Tags: google-maps, overlay, gradient, heatmap

I am using the Javascript v3 API and I have a heatmap working with my data displaying where I have collected certain information. I want to create different heatmap overlays based on the data. 
So I have a load of mobile signal strength data that I am plotting on the map and I want to show the good signal areas in green, bad in red but in areas where there are good and bad samples have an orange/yellow overlay. 
I have found the 'weight' but it seems to be based on the number of occurrences of samples rather than the value of those samples. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may increase the weight to get a result that is more differentiated based on the weight, e.g. by using Math.pow

```
weight:Math.pow(signalStrength, 2)
```

(Modify the exponent to get a result that fits your needs)